# Delta distribution from the correlation/covariance function of two operators

Tags: covariance, dirac-delta, correlation, noise

From [Gardiner](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540208822), it is known that if the correlation function of the operators $X(t)$ such that

$$
\left<X(t)X^{\dagger}(t^{\prime})\right>=\frac{\gamma}{2}e^{-\gamma|t-t^{\prime}|}
$$

It is further mentioned that the limit of $\gamma\rightarrow\infty$ corresponds to a delta function $\delta(t-t^{\prime})$, since

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma}{2}e^{-\gamma|t-t^{\prime}|}dt^{\prime} =1
$$

and

$$
\lim_{\gamma\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\gamma}{2}e^{-\gamma|t-t^{\prime}|}dt^{\prime}=0
$$

for $t\neq t^{\prime}$. I simply do not see how these two conditions lead to the delta function $\delta(t-t^{\prime})$. What is going on here?

**Edit:**
I understand that the first condition is simply the normalization requirement for the delta function. However, I still do not see how the delta function arises. The manifestation of the delta function implies that $X(t)$ is a gaussian white noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi\in C^\infty_C$.  Then clearly we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t')\frac\gamma2 e^{-\gamma|t-t'|}\,dt'\overbrace{=}^{\gamma(t-t')\mapsto t'}\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t-t'/\gamma)e^{-|t'|}\,dt'$$

Using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we find that

$$\lim_{\gamma\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t')\frac\gamma2 e^{-\gamma|t-t'|}\,dt'=\phi(0)$$

which implies that in distribution

$$\lim_{\gamma\to\infty}\frac\gamma2 e^{-\gamma|t-t'|}=\delta(t-t')$$

as was to be shown!

---

---

Interestingly there is not anything special about the function $\gamma2 e^{-\gamma|t-t'|}$.  In fact, for any function $d( t)\in L^1$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d(t)\,dt=1$, then the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ and $\gamma>0$

$$\lim_{\gamma\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t') \gamma d(\gamma(t-t'))\,dt'=\lim_{\gamma\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t-t'/\gamma)d(t')\,dt'=\phi(t)$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am unfamiliar with the Dominated convergence theorem, or its application in this case at the very least, so I will look into it. I want to ask about the first line, where you did $\gamma(t-t^{\prime})\rightarrow t^{\prime}$. Here, you are only changing the variables right? Can you flesh out the steps in detail?

Comment: @kowalski You're welcome.  My Pleasure.  The DCT is a powerful theorem that provides sufficient conditions under which interchanging a limit and an integral is justifiable.  As far as the change of variables, it should be straightforward.

Comment: And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit